# Publish on Facebook to a app user with out login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've read a lot and this is the only solution I get to:

1. The first time the user logs in the app (with publish-actions) you get the token
2. Convert the token to Long-Lived Token
3. You can use it to publish for the next 2 months
4. If the user clicks on a post you send, the token is reset to another 2 months

Am I right? Is that the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all correct. I am not sure about the user click (didn't find that in the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens). You should be ready to handle errors in case the token expires earlier or in case of app uninstalls. I check if the token is still valid by getting the user basic info with the access token I have. If the call is successful, I use the token. If not, I redirect the user app authorization again, get another token, exchange it with another long-lived token, and use that one.

Comment: This is what I read but now I see it doesn't refers to post: "These tokens will be refreshed once per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers.." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending.

Comment: okay, then that refers to the new login with SDK. If you use the new login, Facebook takes care of the token. If like me you think it's too much of a pain, you have to take care of that.